# Abnormal subnormal series

Tags: gr.group-theory

Consider a group $G.$ Is it possible for $G$ to have a subnormal series $G \triangleright G_1 \triangleright \dotsc \triangleright G_n \triangleright \dotsc$ which cycles - that is, with $G_{i+k} \simeq G_i,$ for some $k>1?$ To make the problem more rigid, same question, but with the derived series instead of a subnormal series.

Comment: For the first question, start with a direct product of countably infinitely many copies of a cyclic group of order $2^k$ and then descend in steps of index $2$ going down through each direct factor in turn. It's even a normal series!

Comment: @DerekHolt Cool!

Comment: The second question is interesting in the case $k=1$. Does there exist a group $G$ with $G \cong [G,G] < G$?

Comment: To Derek Holt: If again we allow infinitely generated groups, then the free group of countable rank would answer the question.

Comment: @AlTal Right, this is why the case of $k>1$ is more interesting...

Comment: @AlTal Yes of course! Are there any examples other than free groups?